# Mod a saved game

Tags: dwarf-fortress

in DF2014. im trying to mod the raws for a fortress already in progress. 
tried editing the raws of the saved game itself in: ../data/save/region1../raw/objects/. Even simple things like renaming noble positions arent working.
 id also like to be able to make new objects, even loin clothes in my own Clothier's Workshop. Tried making a custom workshop, since i couldnt find the raws for the current building. And to change the colors of some things. (wouldnt it be nice to be able to paint your buildings?) 
Is any of this still possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone finally answered over [here](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014_Talk:Modding_guide).
in short you can only edit existing objects. in this case changing the colors of objects. The color is the DISPLAY_COLOR tag as described in [here](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Modding_guide#Modding_plants) and [here](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Color). The rest requires changing entities, or making new objects, which you cant do in a saved game.

e.g. to paint wood white:
in material_template_default.txt, under [MATERIAL_TEMPLATE:WOOD_TEMPLATE], change [DISPLAY_COLOR] to read [DISPLAY_COLOR:7:0:15]

(changing [STATE_COLOR] isnt enough)